# Header correct, but compile error(identifier not found)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to include [vdb](https://github.com/zdevito/vdb) in a project (github.com/mmp/pbrt-v2)

I had try vdb's examples, every example works fine.

but in this project(pbrt), I ran into Error `identifier not found`

here is my code:

```
#include "../vdb.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "shapes/heightfieldImproved.h"
#include "shapes/trianglemesh.h"
#include "paramset.h"

// heightfieldImproved Method Definitions
HeightfieldImproved::HeightfieldImproved(const Transform *o2w, const Transform *w2o, bool ro, int x, int y, const float *zs)
    : Shape(o2w, w2o, ro) {
    nx = x;
    ny = y;
    z = new float[nx*ny];
    memcpy(z, zs, nx*ny*sizeof(float));

    nVoxels[0] = nx - 1;
    nVoxels[1] = ny - 1;
    nVoxels[2] = 1;

    ComputeVertexNormal();
    vdb_line(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

IntelliSense works fine, it knew what `vdb_line()` is, but when I built whole project, the error raised(`"vdb_line": identifier not found`)

I'm using visual studio 2015 on win10

Thanks!

--- edited ---
I change the include as full path

```
#include "C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h"
```

and still get the same error....
there just only one error:

["vdb_line": identifier not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDQ5B.png)

full log

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libpbrt, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>
1>  Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>      if exist   (   -d -v -t -o ..\core\pbrtparse.cpp ..\core\pbrtparse.yy  )
1>      if exist   (   -o..\core\pbrtlex.cpp ..\core\pbrtlex.ll  )
1>
1>  Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>  heightfieldImproved.cpp
1>..\shapes\heightfieldImproved.cpp(25): error C3861: 'vdb_line': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

--- edited2 ---
After I change the order of include, as follow:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h"
```

I get lots of errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: libpbrt, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>
1>  Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>      if exist   (   -d -v -t -o ..\core\pbrtparse.cpp ..\core\pbrtparse.yy  )
1>      if exist   (   -o..\core\pbrtlex.cpp ..\core\pbrtlex.ll  )
1>
1>  Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>  heightfieldImproved.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2def.h(221): error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(477) : see declaration of 'sockaddr'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2def.h(421): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2def.h(421): error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2def.h(615): error C2011: 'sockaddr_in' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(304) : see declaration of 'sockaddr_in'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(136): error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(60) : see declaration of 'fd_set'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(180): error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(103) : see declaration of 'timeval'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(236): error C2011: 'hostent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(159) : see declaration of 'hostent'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(249): error C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(172) : see declaration of 'netent'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(256): error C2011: 'servent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(179) : see declaration of 'servent'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(268): error C2011: 'protoent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(191) : see declaration of 'protoent'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(364): error C2011: 'WSAData' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(314) : see declaration of 'WSAData'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(462): error C2011: 'sockproto' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(486) : see declaration of 'sockproto'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(504): error C2011: 'linger' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(523) : see declaration of 'linger'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1650): error C2375: 'accept' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(734) : see declaration of 'accept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1672): error C2375: 'bind' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(739) : see declaration of 'bind'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1691): error C2375: 'closesocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(744) : see declaration of 'closesocket'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1710): error C2375: 'connect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(746) : see declaration of 'connect'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1731): error C2375: 'ioctlsocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(751) : see declaration of 'ioctlsocket'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1752): error C2375: 'getpeername' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(756) : see declaration of 'getpeername'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1773): error C2375: 'getsockname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(761) : see declaration of 'getsockname'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1796): error C2375: 'getsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(766) : see declaration of 'getsockopt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1817): error C2375: 'htonl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(773) : see declaration of 'htonl'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1834): error C2375: 'htons' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(775) : see declaration of 'htons'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1852): error C2375: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(777) : see declaration of 'inet_addr'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1870): error C2375: 'inet_ntoa' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(779) : see declaration of 'inet_ntoa'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1971): error C2375: 'listen' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(781) : see declaration of 'listen'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(1989): error C2375: 'ntohl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(785) : see declaration of 'ntohl'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2006): error C2375: 'ntohs' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(787) : see declaration of 'ntohs'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2026): error C2375: 'recv' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(789) : see declaration of 'recv'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2051): error C2375: 'recvfrom' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(795) : see declaration of 'recvfrom'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2077): error C2375: 'select' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(803) : see declaration of 'select'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2101): error C2375: 'send' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(810) : see declaration of 'send'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2126): error C2375: 'sendto' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(816) : see declaration of 'sendto'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2152): error C2375: 'setsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(824) : see declaration of 'setsockopt'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2174): error C2375: 'shutdown' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(831) : see declaration of 'shutdown'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2195): error C2375: 'socket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(835) : see declaration of 'socket'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2220): error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(842) : see declaration of 'gethostbyaddr'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2240): error C2375: 'gethostbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(847) : see declaration of 'gethostbyname'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2258): error C2375: 'gethostname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(849) : see declaration of 'gethostname'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2298): error C2375: 'getservbyport' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(853) : see declaration of 'getservbyport'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2317): error C2375: 'getservbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(857) : see declaration of 'getservbyname'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2335): error C2375: 'getprotobynumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(861) : see declaration of 'getprotobynumber'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2352): error C2375: 'getprotobyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(863) : see declaration of 'getprotobyname'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2373): error C2375: 'WSAStartup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(867) : see declaration of 'WSAStartup'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2392): error C2375: 'WSACleanup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(871) : see declaration of 'WSACleanup'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2409): error C2375: 'WSASetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(873) : see declaration of 'WSASetLastError'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2426): error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(875) : see declaration of 'WSAGetLastError'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2447): error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(877) : see declaration of 'WSAIsBlocking'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2465): error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(879) : see declaration of 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2483): error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(881) : see declaration of 'WSASetBlockingHook'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2501): error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(883) : see declaration of 'WSACancelBlockingCall'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2524): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(885) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2552): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(893) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2579): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(901) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2605): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(908) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2631): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(915) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2659): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(922) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2683): error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(931) : see declaration of 'WSACancelAsyncRequest'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinSock2.h(2704): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(933) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncSelect'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(60): error C3861: 'closesocket': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(102): error C2568: '=' : unable to resolve function overload
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(835): could be 'SOCKET socket(int,int,int)'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(102): error C3861: 'socket': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(107): error C2079: 'serv_name' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(108): error C2228: left of '.sin_family' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(109): error C2228: left of '.sin_addr' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(109): error C2228: left of '.S_un' must have class/struct/union
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(109): error C2228: left of '.S_addr' must have class/struct/union
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(109): error C3861: 'htonl': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(110): error C2228: left of '.sin_port' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'int'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(110): error C3861: 'htons': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(111): error C2568: '==' : unable to resolve function overload
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(746): could be 'int connect(SOCKET,const sockaddr *,int)'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(111): error C3861: 'connect': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(126): error C2568: '=' : unable to resolve function overload
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(810): could be 'int send(SOCKET,const char *,int,int)'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(126): error C3861: 'send': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(215): error C3861: 'WSAGetLastError': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(215): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'int'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(229): error C2079: 'wsaData' uses undefined struct 'WSAData'
1>C:\Users\ssarcandy\Documents\GitHub\pbrt-v2\src\vdb.h(230): error C3861: 'WSAStartup': identifier not found
2>------ Build started: Project: pbrt, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libpbrt.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: vdb_line() isn't it a member of class HeightfieldImproved?

Comment: Can you include the full error message you get when building the project?

Comment: vdb_line() is a function defined in vdb.h.

Comment: Have you tried moving that `include` statement somewhere after including `stdafx.h`?

Comment: I move the include next line after `stdafx.h` and it generate **lots of** error....

Comment: Great, now we're going somewhere. Can you also include those in the post?

Comment: @lonut I updated into the post. thank you!

Comment: Have you modified vdb.h in any way? The line numbers from all the errors reported in this header are off by 1 compared with what they should be according to the file from https://github.com/zdevito/vdb .

Comment: i'm using the header file from vdb readme link, that have one line different from  github.com/zdevito/vdb vdb.h. i checked the line number in error log , it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper place to include `vdb.h` is after `stdafx.h`, not before. By default if your project is set to use precompiled headers, it will ignore all includes that come before `stdafx.h` in a source file. You should have seen a warning telling you this before that error that you mentioned in your post:

```
warning C4627: '#include "vdb.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
note: Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
```

This is way it later failed the compilation telling you it can't find that function.

Now if you move the include statement after `stdafx.h` you get a lot of errors, most of them about duplicate definitions of WinSock related names.
That's because you end up including both `winsock.h` and `WinSock2.h`. The first one gets included from `windows.h` which in turn gets included on a long chain starting with `stdafx.h` and ending in `parallel.h`. The second one gets included directly from `vdb.h`.

To fix this you can go about in two ways:

**1. Make `windows.h` not include `winsock.h` automatically**

To do this, you define the macro WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN at the top of `stdafx.h`, before any other include statements.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

This disables the inclusion of a few more headers besides `winsock.h`, so you might get some new errors when you do it. You could try to fix these by including the appropriate headers directly where needed.

I'm not familiar with the PBRT project and it's source code, I don't know if it actually uses WinSock or it just got the header included without it realizing, so I can't tell you exactly what new problems you might run into.

**2. Convert `vdb` to using winsock instead of winsock2**

I'm not familiar with this project either so I can't tell you how much work this would involve. But on a first look it looks doable if for some reason the first method fails.

Comment: GREAT THANKS!!! thanks for your clearly explanation about `stdafx.h`, after trying method 2, all works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know what vdb_line is. The line

#include "../vdb.h"

is probably not correct since the header file, according to your github link, does have the *cdb_line* deklaration. Try including vdb.h with the explicit path to verify. Place the header file correctly relative your working directory to include it with "../vdb.h".

Intellisense has it owns mechanics. By default, it only uses standard include directories to find header files. But other files, even non project files, can be added for intellisense to parse. It is not strange that intellisense knows the *cdb_line* declaraion and the compiler does not but as to why, we would have to look into your visual studio project settings.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I update the question. I include header using absolute path still get same result, IntelliSense works fine but compiler can't find it.